# How to allow a user to create files in a directory but prevent this user from creating and deleting files in the parent directory?

Tags: linux, permissions

I would like to prevent a user (identified by uid) from creating and deleting files in `/tmp`, but allow this user to create files in directory `/tmp/hello`, which is owned by this user. How can I achieve that? Only this user should be prevented from creating and deleting files in `/tmp`, other users whoever have the appropiate permission shouldn't be prevented. `/tmp` is owned by `root`.

Comment: `/tmp` is usually a quite special directory in that everyone is allowed to create files and directories in it. Is there a particular reason you'd want to disallow this user from creating files under `/tmp`? Does it have to do with the location of temporary files? If so, does the software that you use honour the `TMPDIR` environment variable (you would use it to specify another directory to create temporary files in). In short, what is the underlying problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: In fact, I'm running untrusted codes (similar to student's homework) on the system, so I need to make restrictions so that the unstrusted program won't mess up the system. I placed the program in `/tmp/hello`, and I want to make sure this program can only create files in the same directory of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using file ACLs.

You prevent the user `badguy` from creating files in `tmp` with:

```
setfacl -m u:badguy:r-x /tmp
```

And you can allow it to write to the `hello` directory “normally” (allow everyone, `chown` the directory to `badguy`) or, again, with file ACLS:

```
setfacl -m u:badguy:rwx /tmp/hello
```